# Distributing processes in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a python script which loads a machine learning model and classifies text files. My script looks something like this:

```
import sys
for test_file in sys.argv[1:]:
    classify(test_file)
```

I am running the script on 10000 files using python command

```
python script.py my_dir/*.txt
```

Where my_dir contains 10000 of the text files to be classified. The processing of files are independent and I am wondering if the process can be distributed using threading. One solution is to distribute the files in separate folders and run the commands separately which doesn't seem like the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would a simple pool do?  In this case it depends whether you'd be better off with processes or threads. My guess is processes as it is usually the case with Python.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
# from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool    
import sys


def classify(filename):
    print("classified ", filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool()
    p.map(classify, sys.argv[1:])
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Use either from the import statements to select between processes and threads. The interface to both pools is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to simply define a number of thread (1 per processor core) and distribute equally the files in this threads.

```
from threading import Thread

class Distribute(Thread): 
    def __init__(self, files):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.files = files
    def run(self):
        for file in self.files:
            classify(file)

numberOfFile = len(sys.argv[1:])
numberOfThread = 4
numberOfFileByThread = numberOfFile // numberOfThread
threads = [Distribute(sys.argv[1:][i*numberOfFileByThread:(i+1)*numberOfFileByThread ]) for i in range(numberOfThread)]
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
print("All thread running")
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
print("processing completed")
```